# Listbox Item holds data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[Server 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbPz4.png) [Server2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8dwO.png) [Server Config Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycuTj.png)
I am trying to make a video game server manager and I have run into an issue. I want the user to be able to have as many servers as they would like. However I cannot figure out through google searching and just regular messing around how to store the information that the user selects to become associated with the Server they create in the list. Basically when you make Server1 it takes the info you selected from the boxes on the config screen and uses them on the server selection page. But, when you make Server2, the configuration overwrites Server1's configuration. I know my code isn't even setup to be able to do this but I would appreciate a push in the right direction as to which type of code I should use.

Tl:dr I want config options to be associated with ServerX in the server list and each server should have unique settings.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Variables
    string srvName;
    string mapSelect;
    string difSelect;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.srvList.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.srvList_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    private void srvList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(srvList.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            dltButton.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            dltButton.Visible = true;
        }
        //Text being displayed to the left of the server listbox
        mapLabel1.Text = mapSelect;
        difLabel1.Text = difSelect;

    }
    private void crtButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add srvName to srvList
        srvName = namBox1.Text;
        srvList.Items.Add(srvName);

        //Selections
        mapSelect = mapBox1.Text;
        difSelect = difBox1.Text;

        //Write to config file
        string[] lines = { mapSelect, difSelect };
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\mlynch\Desktop\Test\Test.txt", lines);

        //Clear newPanel form
        namBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        mapBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        difBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

        //Return to srvList
        newPanel.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The key is in your question: 'how to store the information'. You're going to have to store settings somewhere. This would typically be in a database, but could be in a text file (or multiple text files), perhaps as XML or json, or other storage media. Your question (if I understand what you're asking) right now is extremely broad, and not really appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might firstly consider how to hold that data in memory. Bear in mind you might need to design a Class with the type of information each "server" has and then you might need to move to handling it in different scenarios on the `WinForm`

Comment: @Jonathan I was actually thinking about doing that but the problem is that when I tried to have the server write to a txt file, I couldn't figure out how to get it to create a file for every new server I created as to prevent overwriting of the previous one. The next issue I had is aesthetic but I wanted specific attributes of the server to be viewable when you select a server from the list. I didn't want all the information to be displayed but there's no way to get C# to read a specific line from a txt file, at least not that I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the issue. Basically I ended up deciding on a write to a txt file and then read from it to display the contents of the file in the server select menu. I also added a delete button so you can delete the servers that you created. it does not have full functionality yet but it is there. So here it what I ended up with and it works perfectly. Thank you all for trying to help.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Variables
    string srvName;
    string mapSelect;
    string mapFile;
    string difSelect;
    string difFile;
    int maxPlayers;
    string plrSelect;
    string plrFile;
    string finalFile;
    string basepath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    string fileName = "config.txt";


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.srvList.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.srvList_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
    private void srvList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Read Server Selection
        string srvSelect = srvList.GetItemText(srvList.SelectedItem);
        string srvOut = System.IO.Path.Combine(basepath, srvSelect, fileName);
        mapFile = File.ReadLines(srvOut).Skip(1).Take(1).First();
        difFile = File.ReadLines(srvOut).Skip(2).Take(1).First();
        plrFile = File.ReadLines(srvOut).Skip(3).Take(1).First();

        //Display Server Selection
        if (srvList.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            dltButton.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            dltButton.Visible = true;
            mapLabel1.Text = mapFile;
            difLabel1.Text = difFile;
            plrLabel1.Text = plrFile;
    }
    private void crtButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set Server Name
        srvName = namBox1.Text;
        string finalpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(basepath, srvName);


        //Check if server name is taken
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(finalpath))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A Server by this name already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            //Add Server to the Server List
            srvList.Items.Add(srvName);

            //Server Configuration
            mapSelect = mapBox1.Text;
            difSelect = difBox1.Text;
            maxPlayers = maxBar1.Value * 2;
            plrSelect = "" + maxPlayers;

            //Clear New Server Form
            namBox1.Text = String.Empty;
            mapBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            difBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

            //Create the Server File
            Directory.CreateDirectory(finalpath);
            finalFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(finalpath, fileName);
            File.Create(finalFile).Close();

            //Write to config file
            string[] lines = { srvName, mapSelect, difSelect, plrSelect };
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@finalFile, lines);

            //Return to srvList
            newPanel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you came up with an approach that worked. You might want to look at storing the info in the text file in some sort of structured format, like json or xml. And then serialize/deserialize it as you read and write. That way you will have strongly typed objects in your code to work with.

Comment: @Jonathan The thing is, the way that information is being written to the text file is a structured format. The only purpose of the file is to store info that is to be later displayed to the user and the File.ReadLines is exactly what allows me to get specific lines that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a recent comment that you had tried saving to a .txt file but it overwrote it anytime you tried to make an additional one. If you wanted to continue with your .txt approach, you could simply set a global integer variable and append it to each file you save.

```
//Variables
string srvName;
string mapSelect;
string difSelect;
int serverNumber = 0;

...

serverNumber++;
string filepath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\mlynch\Desktop\Test\Test", serverNumber.ToString(), ".txt");
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below source code will give you some idea about the direction. Let us start with some initializations:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.srvList.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.srvList_SelectedIndexChanged);
        mapBox1.Items.Add("Germany");
        mapBox1.Items.Add("Russia");

        difBox1.Items.Add("Easy");
        difBox1.Items.Add("Difficult");
    }
```

This is the event handler of the "Create Server" button. It takes server parameters from the screen and writes to a file named as the server.

```
    private void crtButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add srvName to srvList
        srvName = namBox1.Text;
        srvList.Items.Add(srvName);

        //Selections
        mapSelect = mapBox1.Text;
        difSelect = difBox1.Text;

        //Write to config file
        string path = @"C:\Test\" + srvName + ".txt";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
        sw.WriteLine(mapSelect);
        sw.WriteLine(difSelect);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

        //Clear newPanel form
        namBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        mapBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        difBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

        //Return to srvList
        //newPanel.Visible = false;
    }
```

And finally list box event handler is below. Method reads the server parameters from file and displays on the screen.

```
    private void srvList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (srvList.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            dltButton.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            dltButton.Visible = true;
        }

        string path = @"C:\Test\" + srvList.SelectedItem + ".txt";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        //Text being displayed to the left of the server listbox
        mapLabel1.Text = sr.ReadLine();  // mapSelect;
        difLabel1.Text = sr.ReadLine();  // difSelect;

    }
```

Please feel free to ask any questions you have.